# 2 novel series about alternate reality for people in comas

Tags: story-identification

First book starts with main character (female) suddenly conscious in a new reality where people on horses are riding toward her. She explores place where technology doesn’t work (I.e., there are light switches on the wall but they don’t control anything). In second book it’s revealed that everyone in this reality is in a coma or has a major mental condition in ordinary reality. I found the books in a used bookstore in the late 90s.

Comment: I'm getting a strong _[Otherland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otherland)_ vibe here.

Comment: Not Otherland. The people in comas are adults. But a good guess.